# Assigning attributes to JRadio Buttons in Java Swing

Tags: java, eclipse

i am trying to link JRadioButton to an interface and a method that implements that interface. i have two modes which are the attacking and defensive mode and i want the user to be able to click the attack toggle button and have it enabled and when its unclicked then it activates the defensive mode

Code from the class

```
public class AttackMode implements GameBehaviour {

    public boolean behaviourMode(int numOfShips) {
        if(numOfShips < 3){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

Code From Java Swing GUI

private JRadioButton getRdbtnDefensiveMode() {
        if (rdbtnDefensiveMode == null) {
            rdbtnDefensiveMode = new JRadioButton("Defensive Mode");
            rdbtnDefensiveMode.setEnabled();
            rdbtnDefensiveMode.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                    if (arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                         theRules.theMasterShip.setBadAssBehaviour(new DefenceMode());
                         rdbtnAttackMode.setSelected(false);
                    }else if (arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {

                         theRules.theMasterShip.setBadAssBehaviour(new AttackMode());
                         rdbtnAttackMode.setSelected(true);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            });         
            rdbtnDefensiveMode.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 11));
            rdbtnDefensiveMode.setBounds(658, 355, 109, 23);
        }
        return rdbtnDefensiveMode;
    }




private JRadioButton getRdbtnAttackMode() {
        if (rdbtnAttackMode == null) {
            rdbtnAttackMode = new JRadioButton("Attack Mode");
            rdbtnAttackMode.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
                    if (arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                         theRules.theMasterShip.setBadAssBehaviour(new AttackMode());
                         rdbtnDefensiveMode.setSelected(false);
                    }else if (arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {

                         theRules.theMasterShip.setBadAssBehaviour(new DefenceMode());
                        rdbtnDefensiveMode.setSelected(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            rdbtnAttackMode.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 11));
            rdbtnAttackMode.setBounds(658, 265, 109, 23);
        }
        return rdbtnAttackMode;
    }
```

i am expecting that if the attack button is clicked, it should implement the attack method and if unchecked themn it should activate the defence mode button. So one of the buttons must always be enabled

Comment: If you have only two modes, declare one static button and set default mode to defense, when user clicks on a button it switches between modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your buttons to [button group](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/GUI/components/50radio_buttons/25radiobuttons.html)

Like this:

```
ButtonGroup bgroup = new ButtonGroup();
bgroup.add(getRdbtnAttackMode());
bgroup.add(getRdbtnDefensiveMode());
```

For each button create an `ActionListener`, and you will be good